# Error on hidden expression on a paginated report

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, rdl, powerbi-paginated-reports

I have a report which have worked fine for a while, and now I would like to update it, but while testing my hidden expressions give me an error. If I remove the expression, then there is no problem, but as long as they are there I get the error.

The expression is the following:

```
=
iif(
  isnothing(
    

First(Fields!wc_america.Value, "position_lists")

  )
  ,True,False
)
```

And the error I get is the following:

> The 'Hidden' expression for the image 'Image4' contains an error:
> Request for the permission of type
> 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=123456' failed.

I have seen others have the same error, but have not been able to find a solution.

Can someone here help me? I've tried recreating the expression, but nothing helps.

Comment: Check if this helps https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/31490332-c2f7-48a4-9928-29916ce002b4/request-for-the-permission-of-type-systemsecuritypermissionssecuritypermission-mscorlib?forum=sqlreportingservices